# WebAdministration module does not expose their cmdlets

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-7.5, powershell-3.0, web-administration

Given MS Server 2008 r2, IIS 7.0 upgraded to 7.5
Powershell 2.0 upgraded to 3.0

Execute command `import-module WebAdministration`
It completes without errors.
Then call `get-command -module WebAdministration`
It discovers that only two commands are exposed by module:

> CommandType     Name
>   -----------     ----
>   Alias           Begin-WebCommitDelay
>   Alias           End-WebCommitDelay

So no any other method like `Get-WebSite` for example.

Why powershell does not see all available cmdlets that has to be contained in WebAdministration?

I have my development Win7 machine and everything works good. Have access to all what I need.

UPD as was suggested in comment provide you with output of importing run with `debug` switch:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> import-module WebAdministration -
Force -Debug
VERBOSE: Loading module from path
'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\WebAdmini
stration.psd1'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):y
VERBOSE: Loading 'Assembly' from path
'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.IIS.PowerShell.Framework\7.5.0.0__31bf3
856ad364e35\Microsoft.IIS.PowerShell.Framework.dll'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
VERBOSE: Loading 'TypesToProcess' from path
'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\iisprovid
er.types.ps1xml'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
VERBOSE: Loading 'FormatsToProcess' from path
'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\iisprovid
er.format.ps1xml'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
VERBOSE: Loading module from path
'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\Microsoft
.IIS.PowerShell.Provider.dll'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
VERBOSE: Loading module from path
'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\WebAdmini
strationAliases.ps1'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
VERBOSE: Dot-sourcing the script file
'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\WebAdmini
strationAliases.ps1'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
VERBOSE: Exporting alias 'Begin-WebCommitDelay'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
VERBOSE: Exporting alias 'End-WebCommitDelay'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
VERBOSE: Importing alias 'Begin-WebCommitDelay'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
(default is "Y"):
VERBOSE: Importing alias 'End-WebCommitDelay'.

Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help
```

UPD2: Seems problems related with version of Powershell, that is 3.0. When I run powershell with `-version 2` WebAdmininstration's cmdlets work properly. But why 3.0 misses WebAdministration's commands, that's question.

Comment: Try `Import-Module webadministration -Force -Debug` and maybe post the output.

Comment: @jisaak updated my question

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything wrong there except the missing methods. Sorry, can't help you. You can try to reinstall IIS, check windows features and maybe even the .NET Version?

Comment: I use this command and it seems to work - Invoke-Command -Command {Import-Module WebAdministration}